# Java CAS JBoss Steam Liferay

Tags: jboss, liferay, cas, steam

I use CAS to authenticate users for the application which integrated into Liferay 5.2.3. The CAS login is fine! I can login to the Liferay. But when I try to start the application I get NullPointer exception because the Principal Object does not contain the username:

```
15:16:45,304 DEBUG [AuthenticationFilter] removing gateway attribute from session
15:16:45,508 ERROR [STDERR] java.lang.NullPointerException
15:16:45,509 ERROR [STDERR] at com.activitree.action.CustomIdentity.ssoLogin(CustomIdentity.java:205)
```

I try to get the Principal like this:

```
return (Principal) FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().getExternalContext().getUserPrincipal();
```

- CAS Server version: 3.4.6
- Seam 2.2.0.GA
- JBoss 4.2.3.GA

I don't know the CAS client version.

Thanks your help

Comment: And the exception is?

Comment: 15:16:45,304 DEBUG [AuthenticationFilter] removing gateway attribute from session
15:16:45,508 ERROR [STDERR] java.lang.NullPointerException
15:16:45,509 ERROR [STDERR]     at com.activitree.action.CustomIdentity.ssoLogin(CustomIdentity.java:205)

Comment: I did a Debug so the username is not in the Principal Object.